# Is "lab" too informal a word for a formal cover letter?

Tags: application, postdocs, application-cover-letter

When applying for a postdoc position, it makes sense to write something like this in the cover letter:

> Dear Professor NAME. I am writing to apply for POSITION in your lab

What I'm stuck on, is that a cover letter is a formal letter, so should be written in a formal register. However, the word "lab" is an abbreviation and so inherently informal, which makes it seem wrong. On the other hand "laboratory" sounds even more wrong because no-one says "at my laboratory" in speech.

Is the word "lab" appropriate in this context?

Comment: Abbreviations aren't inherently informal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with you that both lab and laboratory don't sound good. Maybe you could use "group" instead?